# Redefining special characters as macros

Tags: macros, extended-characters

I'd like to redefine some special characters as macros. Essentially, I want to tell lualatex to execute some user-defined commands whenever encountering some special characters, such as á, ḿ, etc.

I've found this solution. 
http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-activechars.html

```
\catcode`\z=\active
\def z{Yawn, I'm tired}%
```

Unfortunately I think it doesn't work for special characters. When I put á at where z is in the above code, I got the following error:

```
!Improper alphabetic constant.
```

Any suggestion? Please also help to add relevant tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your á is not a single glyph but an `a` with a combining accent U+0301. With the proper glyph U+00E1 is works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\á =\active
\def á {Yawn, I'm tired}%
á 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ulrike Fischer. How did you find out that the á in my original post is an a with a combing accent?

Comment: I knew it ;-). Only this could explain your error. But I could also confirm it by converting it in babelpad.