# Redefine German Unicode quotes as German LaTeX quotes

Tags: unicode, substitution

When writing German text, one quotes like this when wanting to use the

```
"`correct"'
```

quotes.

As a user of [NEO 2](http://neo-layout.org), I got the quotes the above code produces on my keyboard:

> „correct“

I heard you can redefine any character with LaTeX. When searching for how to do it, the closest anything I was able to find came is [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266108/107848). But I can't even compile the code the answer states:

```
ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 

l.4 \catcode`\á
                 =\active
--- HELP ---
This is usually caused by a LaTeX command expecting but not finding
either a number or a length as an argument. You may have omitted an
argument, or a square bracket in the text may have been mistaken for
the beginning of an optional argument. This error is also caused by
putting \protect in front of either a length command or a command such
as \value that produces a number.
```

Without being able to play around with it, I wasn't able to figure out how to make the quotes thing work. So how is it done?

Comment: @UTF-8 it would be much better if you had made a small complete document showing the problem text (which is what Kurt meant) What did you try, and what output did you get,  „correct“ should not give an error even without any extra definitions

Comment: note question and answer that you reference are not using utf-8

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right. But I simply tried to compile the code the answer stated. I didn't change anything, so I didn't add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. But I suppose even if it worked, it would've broken when switching to UTF-8.

Comment: Yes That's the point: the answer depends on the encoding used,  the answer there needs to be saved as iso-8859-1 to work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using UTF-8 input then

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{201E}{\glqq}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{201C}{\grqq}
```